# ViewState is cleared on postback in DataBoundControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I'm developing a control that inherits from DataBoundControl. The databinding works but the viewstate is cleared on postback for some reason? I've tried all sorts of solutions like making it implement the ViewStateModeById attribute, but nothing works. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

```
public class Test : DataBoundControl, INamingContainer
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        if (this.Visible && !_isDataBound)
        {
            // If the developer wants to show it on click or something then they will have to call DataBind() themselves
            // If this control has just been put on a page and there is no code behind then we need to make it get data and call DataBind
            FlagForDataBinding();
            DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_isDataBound || RequiresDataBinding)
        {
            DataBind();
        }
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }

    private bool _isDataBound = false;
    public override object DataSource
    {
        get { return Enumerable.Range(0, 10); }
        set
        {}
    }

    public virtual void FlagForDataBinding()
    {
        this.DataSource = null;
        if (_isDataBound)
        {
            _isDataBound = false;
        }
        else
            this.RequiresDataBinding = true;
    }

    protected override void PerformSelect()
    {
        if (!IsBoundUsingDataSourceID)
        {
            // If using .DataSource then databinding starts here
            // (Because the the data has alredy been retrieved when doing .DataSource = )
            OnDataBinding(EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        GetData().Select(CreateDataSourceSelectArguments(), OnDataReady);

        RequiresDataBinding = false;
        MarkAsDataBound();

        OnDataBound(EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    protected virtual void OnDataReady(IEnumerable data)
    {
        if (IsBoundUsingDataSourceID)
        {
            // If using .DataSourceId then databinding starts here
            OnDataBinding(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        PerformDataBinding(data);
    }

    protected override void PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data)
    {
        this.Controls.Clear();
        if (data != null)
        {
            OutputItems((IEnumerable<int>)data);
        }
        base.PerformDataBinding(data);
    }

    public override void DataBind()
    {
        this.EnsureChildControls();
        if (!_isDataBound || RequiresDataBinding)
        {
            base.OnDataBinding(EventArgs.Empty);
            base.DataBind();
            _isDataBound = true;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OutputItems(IEnumerable<int> items)
    {
        this.Controls.Clear();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var lnk = new LinkButton {Text = item.ToString(), CommandArgument = item.ToString()};
            lnk.Click += lnk_Click;
            this.Controls.Add(lnk);
        }
        this.Controls.Add(new Literal{Text = "Total: " + Total});
    }

    void lnk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int toAdd = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
        Total += toAdd;
        FlagForDataBinding();
    }

    public int Total {
        get { return (int?) ViewState["Total"] ?? 0; }
        set { ViewState["Total"] = value; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting EnableViewState="true" and ViewStateMode="Enabled" on the DataBoundControl.

Also, make sure EnableViewState="true" for the page as well.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.enableviewstate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go when I get home. If its just that I'll kick myself.

Comment: Ha, yeah.  I figured it was worth mentioning.  Sometimes it's easy to overlook the simple stuff.

Comment: Nope, didn't work :/ Strangely the click event only fires every other postback as well.